# Why those two pieces of code return different outputs?

Tags: python-3.x

Code snippet #1:

```
d = census_df[census_df.SUMLEV==50].copy()
d['max'] = d[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013','POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']].max(axis=1)
    d['min'] = d[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013','POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']].min(axis=1)
    d['diff'] = d['max'] - d['min']

d[d['diff'] == d['diff'].max()].iloc[0]['CTYNAME']
```

Code snippet #2:

```
d = census_df[census_df["SUMLEV"] == 50]
d= d.groupby(["STNAME"])["POPESTIMATE2015'].nlargest(3)
d["max"] = d[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013','POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']].max(axis=1)
d["min"] = d[['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011','POPESTIMATE2012','POPESTIMATE2013','POPESTIMATE2014','POPESTIMATE2015']].min(axis=1)
d["Diff"] = d["max"] - d["min"]
ans = d[d["Diff"] == d["Diff"]].max().iloc[0]["CTYNAME"]
```

Comment: The second one has a typo, `"POPESTIMATE2015'`.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide details. What are these code snippets supposed to do? What is `census_df`? What is the expected output and what are the actual outputs? How are they different?

Comment: Because the second snippet takes max from ALL rows, where condition is met, then filtering only the first row of result (there's just one row already after max), whereas the first one just from 1 column - ```diff``` - and then filters out the top row. max from rows will return differently depending on row elements type (str/numbers/Boolean/lists etc). The first one looks way more logical tbh

Comment: Thank you.. now its clear. appreciate it.